# Grid ignores ClipToBounds in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, clipping

Given a really basic `Grid`, with `ColumnDefinition`'s width set to `*`, the hardcoded width attribute of the button's contained within are ignored and these child elements are clipped. They are not clipped with a width set to `Auto`.

This clipping is prevented if correct `MinWidth`s are set on each  `ColumnDefinition`, but this is not exactly dynamic.

Am I doing things wrong or is this the best WPF has to offer?

[image]

becomes

[image]

Markup:

```
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="120">AAAAA</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="120">BBBB</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="120">CCCCC</Button>
    </Grid>
```

I would like the buttons to appear as per the first image when there is room, and as image three when there is none (i.e. no clipping under any circumstances).

[image]

Comment: Are you able to add a diagram for what you want to happen when the window is minimized? are the buttons always 120 width or do you want them to shrink with the window resizing? thx

Comment: @SWilko updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I've solved it as follows:

The key is the `MinWidth` attribute in the `ColumnDefinition`.

```
 <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=spLeft }"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=spMid }"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=spRight }"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="Red" Grid.Column="0" Name="spLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button  Width="120">AAAAA</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Name="spMid">
            <Button  Width="120">BBBB</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="Blue" Name="spRight" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button  Width="120">CCCCC</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a MinWidth to the Grid:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" ClipToBounds="False" MinWidth="360">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="120">AAAAA</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="120">BBBB</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="120">CCCCC</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Arnaud, thanks for the answer. I was looking for a dynamic approach that didn't require me to hardcode a literal `minwidth`. See my answer for this solution.

Comment: Hi Maxp, technically this is a correct answer to your question though I can understand you wanted something that you hadn't expressed. Plus anyway MinWidth is the answer.